# Why does Mutating Webhook require both parent resource and subresource?

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks

This is related to [Dynamic Admission Control](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/).

Mutating the `status` subresource in mutating admission webhook requires both parent resource and subresource, for eg - `Node` and `Node/status` present in the webhook i.e.:

```yaml
...
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
    apiVersions:
  - v1
    operations:
  - CREATE
  - UPDATE
    resources:
  - nodes
  - nodes/status
    ...
```

If I try to specify just `nodes` in the webhook, the status is not updated (`status` can be updated for node, see [Advertise Extended Resources for a Node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/extended-resource-node/)). Whereas if I include both resource and the subresource, the mutation is successful.

I was able to find: 
[Kubernetes: Is it possible to mutate the status subresources in the mutation admission webhooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59564757/15412365)
regarding this but, it too does not mention the reason for doing so.

What is the reason to add both parent resource and subresource for modifying the `status` subresource?